# How do I define the state at a given register in binary and hex?

Tags: assembly, mips

So I have a byte 0xA3 that has been loaded into $t7 using a lb instruction and I have to depict the state of register $7 in both in binary and in hex. Going about this, would the state in binary and hex be the actual address? Ex: 0x004000A3, or is it something totally different.

I also need to do the same with a character. What would the different be for a character compared to the byte?

Comment: Registers don't have memory addresses, that part doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Besides what unwind has said, a register (and also memory value) always hold a **value**, not binary or hex or character. Binary, decimal, hex, floating-point, character, etc... are different **representations** of that value.